# postgis update multipolygon with st_makevalid() gives error

Tags: postgis

I have a table with a few invalid geometries (empty rings, self-intersections). I'd like to fix them up something like this:

```
update mytable
set geomcolumn = st_makevalid(geomcolumn)
where id = 123;
```

and I get "**ERROR: Geometry type (GeometryCollection) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)"**

is there some other function I need to wrap the st_makevalid() in to get a compatible type, or something else?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[ST_CollectionExtract](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_CollectionExtract.html) will pull out a particular type of component from a `GeometryCollection`.  For example, `ST_CollectionExtract(geom, 3)` will return a `Polygon` or `MultiPolygon`.

Since your column type is `MultiPolygon`, you may need to wrap `ST_CollectionExtract` with yet another function, `ST_Multi`, to coerce `Polygon` geometries into single-component `MultiPolygons`.

Beware `ST_MakeValid` - it generally does what you'd expect it to, but it's not magic and it can occasionally "correct" your geometry in unexpected ways.  It's a good idea to run a `SELECT` query first, to see what it has in mind.

Comment: that's the ticket. I used the following to 1) find the invalid rows in PGAdmin, 2) preview them in the QGIS DB Manager, and 3) update them in PGAdmin:select geomcol, id, st_isvalid(geomcol), st_isvalidreason(geomcol)
from mylayer
where st_isvalid(geomcol)) = false;

select id, st_multi(st_collectionextract(st_makevalid(geomcol), 3))
from mylayer
where id in (123, 456);

update mylayer
set geomcol = st_multi(st_collectionextract(st_makevalid(geomcol), 3))
where id in (123, 456);

Answer (score 18):

You need to update your geometry column by extracting `Multipolygons` from `GeometryCollection`. Simply run below query and you are good to go

```
update table set geomcol = st_multi(st_collectionextract(st_makevalid(geomcol),3))
    where st_isvalid(geomcol) = false;
```

Comment: Although the accepted answer gives detailed info on what is to be done, a good example is always worth a +1! (EDIT: which I gave to the accepted answer as well obviously)